# Problem Installing Java EE SDK From Wizard?

Tags: sdk, jakarta-ee, installation, wizard

Upon fixing my [earlier problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653684/server-is-not-loading-compiling-the-latest-version-of-code-in-eclipse) where, I uninstalled both, JRE AND Java EE, and then successfully reinstalled JRE, the problem started with installing Java EE, when, upon clicking the Java EE Installation `.exe` file, and waiting for a few minutes, (for the extraction of files to take place) the main Java EE 5 SDK Update 7 Installation Wizard was loaded, I clicked the next button, then the license agreement appeared, where, I switched the radio button and proceeded to the next button. And its in the following step, the problem started, where I had to choose the Installation Directory, I kept the pre-existing location, and, clicked Next. Then, absolutely nothing happened, the `Back` , `Next` , `Cancel` , and `Help` buttons were unresponsive/frozen. But the file chooser still worked upon clicking the Browse button (in that same frame).

[Here](http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1257095657038463200.png) is that frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be with an earlier failed uninstall of Java EE SDK. If a file named `productregistry.access.TMP` is still present in the `C:\WINDOWS\system32` directory, then, delete it. It probably has been left by a failed uninstallation of Java EE SDK. Then, proceed to restart the Java EE SDK wizard, and things should be fine by then.